# AWS Lambda using Node Js gives "connect ETIMEDOUT" on http.request()

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ecmascript-6, aws-lambda, nodejs-server

I have written lambda function that retrieve s3 Url whenever any new object created on s3 bucket.
after retrieve s3Url this lambda make request to my server over REST Call.

I observed cloud watcher.
It failed to send request to my Server
I don't want to use external packages in my lambda & i want to make it lightweight that's why i used nodeJ's
https.

Here is my Lambda code

```
 exports.handler =  (event,context,callback) => {
  // Extract S3 Url and id From S3 object present in event
  const https = require('https');
  let {s3 , awsRegion} = event["Records"][0];
  let {object : {key}, bucket : {name}} = s3;
  let s3URL = `https://${name}.s3.${awsRegion}.amazonaws.com/${key}`;
  console.log("sURL",s3URL);
  let _id = key.split('/')[0];
  console.log("id",_id);
//Making http request to my server
  let body='';
  // the post options
  let optionsPost = {
     host: 'xyz.abc.com', 
    path: '/api/v1/apipath',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'XYZ',
    'id' : _id
  }
  };
  const keepAliveAgent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true });
  optionsPost.agent = keepAliveAgent;
  let reqPost =  https.request(optionsPost, function(res) {
      console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          body += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', function () {
        console.log("Result", body.toString());
         context.succeed("Sucess")
      });
       res.on('error', function () {
        console.log("Result Error", body.toString());
        context.done(null, 'FAILURE');
        callback(new Error('failure')) // to return error
      });
  });
  reqPost.write(JSON.stringify({ s3Url: s3URL,userName: 'SYSTEM' }));
  reqPost.end();
};
```

And here is my cloud watcher Error

> { "errorType": "Error", "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT 34.255.225.41:443", "code": "ETIMEDOUT", "errno": "ETIMEDOUT", "syscall": "connect", "address": "34.255.225.41", "port": 443, "stack": [ "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.255.225.41:443", " at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)" ] }

Comment: look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70582121/getting-etimedout-error-in-aws-lambda-function/74168986#74168986

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are attempting to access S3 (or any other AWS resource) through the AWS SDK or directly through any HTTP call from a Lambda then either one of the following scenarios must be true:

- Your Lambda is not set up to run in a VPC
- Your Lambda is set up to run in a VPC, and the VPC is set up with a [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) or is set to use [AWS PrivateLink](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/concepts.html).

In AWS, VPCs provide two network segments, a '**public**' network and a '**private**' network. All resources in the VPC can communicate with other resources in the VPC regardless of which segment they are on. Resources on the **public** segment of the VPC will route public-internet bound traffic through the Internet Gateway that is provided on most VPCs out-of-the-box. However, any containers/resources that are set up on a VPC's **private** segment are firewalled and do not have routing for public internet addresses without either installing a NAT or creating interface endpoints for the VPC.

**Lambda functions that are configured to run inside a VPC create the container which runs the code inside the ***private*** segment of the VPC**. Without either a NAT or interface endpoints, the Lambda can only access any resources within the VPC through their internal IP addresses/DNS names.

When using the AWS SDK without other qualifiers, the resources are generally accessed from their public-facing service domain name (such as from AWS S3), attempts to access them in a Lambda behind a VPC with no NAT gateway will result in your function receiving `ETIMEDOUT` errors. This generally occurs when using any of the AWS SDK within a Lambda for the same reasons.

If your function needs to be behind a VPC to access other resources, then you should either set up a [NAT Gateway on your VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/) or you should configure [VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc-endpoints.html) for your lambda function to use.

Otherwise, you should ensure that your Lambda is **not** set up to use the VPC as running it inside the VPC incurs additional cold-start times latency along with the network connectivity challenges.