# Getting ETIMEDOUT error in AWS Lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops

I have configured VPC in my Lambda because I wanted to use AWS EFS and I get the following error when my lambda function tries to get data from third party application.

> "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.157.139.105:443 at
> TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) "

Can someone please guide me what I'm missing here?

Comment: This is caused when your request response is not received in given time. Please check the timeout value in General Configuration of your Lambda function and make sure you get the response back within that timeframe from your third part application. Also, make sure your third party application is reachable from your VPC.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Myz it is reachable because sometimes it works and most of the time it gives me this error. i have my lambda timeout as 15 mins and api gateway default timeout is 29 sec which i cant change .

Comment: @Timberman so my use case is im making request to lambda from my react application and from my lambda to third part application and while doing this sometimes im getting endpoint request timed out error due to the above reason.sometimes it works but most of the time it gives me above error.

Comment: @Myz is it because of third party as it is not giving me the 
 response in particular timeframe?but if this is the case than how come from postman im getting the response quickly no matter how many times i try

Comment: @pawan007 Typically, 15m timeout is more than enough to get the response back. Is your VPC behind some proxy or firewall?

Comment: @pawan007 Have you tried to access any other URL from your Lambda?

Comment: @Myz no i dont have firewall or proxy behind my VPC . i didn't tried with other url i will try and will let you know accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue ,
the problem was with the VPC .

from [AWS Troubleshoot networking issues in Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/troubleshooting-networking.html) :

> By default, Lambda runs your functions in an internal virtual private
> cloud (VPC) with connectivity to AWS services and the internet. To
> access local network resources, you can configure your function to
> connect to a VPC in your account. When you use this feature, you
> manage the function's internet access and network connectivity with
> Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC) resources.

I solved it by creating a VPC with two private subnets, VPC endpoints, a public subnet with a NAT gateway, and an internet gateway. Internet-bound traffic from functions in the private subnets is routed to the NAT gateway using a route table , according to the AWS instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html).

I built the VPC in cloudFormation using [this yaml](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/templates/vpc-privatepublic.yaml) (from the AWS documention above) and connected the Lambda function to the new VPC, its subnets and security group.